# Wrap each matching word with quotationmarks

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have several lines in Notepad++ which looks similar to this

```
A8s KQo QTs A9s A9s AJo AJo 99  KQo A5s
```

What I would like to do is to wrap each word in quotation marks, followed by a comma is possible.

I've tried matching against `[A-Za-z\d]{2-3}`, but I dont get any matches.

Desired result:

```
 "A8s", "KQo",  "QTs",  //etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What nickb said is true, but you might want to consider adding word boundaries:

```
\b[A-Za-z0-9]{2,3}\b
```

Otherwise if your input had longer words, too like

```
A8s KQo ABCD 1234
```

You would get results like

```
"A8s" "KQo" "ABC"D "123"4
```

The word boundary makes sure that you can only match entire words.

Comment: Hmm ok, but i dont get any matches on `(\b[A-Za-z0-9]{2,3}\b)`. Am I supposed to enter it in another way in notepad++?

Comment: @Johan I do get matches. With and without parentheses. Make sure to a) upgrade to Notepad++ 6 and b) active regex mode for the search

Comment: Notepad 5.9x was the problem. Even though i pressed update I still got the 5.x version. Had to download it manually for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because in quantifiers, you need a comma, not a dash:

```
[A-Za-z\d]{2,3}
            ^
```

Otherwise, you were literally matching the characters `{2-3}`, so your current regex would match things like:

```
A{2-3}
```

You probably want to wrap this in a capturing group, like this:

```
([A-Za-z\d]{2,3})
```

And then replace it with a reference to what was captured, but surrounded by quotes, similar to this:

```
"$1",
```